# Python Unicode Encode Error ordinal not in range<128> with Euro Sign

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, ascii

I have to read an XML file in Python and grab various things, and I ran into a frustrating error with Unicode Encode Error that I couldn't figure out even with googling.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
with open('data.txt','w') as fout:
   #do a lot of stuff
   nameObj = data.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
   name = nameObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue
   #... do more stuff
   fout.write(','.join((name,bunch of other stuff))
```

This spectacularly crashes when a name entry I am parsing contains a Euro sign. Here is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I understand why Euro sign will screw it up (because it's at 128, right?), but I thought doing # coding: utf-8 would fix that. I also tried adding .encode(utf-8) so that the name looks instead like

```
name = nameObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue.encode(utf-8)
```

But that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong? (I am using Python 2.7.3 if anyone wants to know)

EDIT: Python crashes out on the fout.write() line -- it will go through fine where the name field is like:

```
<name>United States, USD</name>
```

But will crap out on name fields like:

```
<name>France, € </name>
```

Comment: Where is the exception being generated? Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: the fout.write() line is where it craps out. The error is up there -- the name obj where it crashes I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

when you are opening a file in python using the `open` built-in function you will always read the file in ascii. To access it in another encoding you have to use codecs:

```
import codecs
fout = codecs.open('data.txt','w','utf-8')
```

Comment: For a 2.x file, you read a string of bytes -- no particular encoding. Bytes don't know that they're ASCII bytes or UTF-8 bytes. If you write a `unicode` object to the file, it gets encoded with the default ASCII encoding, which will probably fail. That's where `codecs.open` comes into play. It adds a wrapper that handles encoding to and from Unicode and bytes.

Comment: This is probably a better answer than mine, since it lets you deal exclusively with Unicode data (letting just the IO code worry about character encodings). You can also use `io.open` in Python 2.7, which also accepts an encoding parameter. It's the default `open` in Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're getting Unicode data from your XML parser, but you're not encoding it before writing it out. You can explicitly encode the result before writing it out to the file:

```
text = ",".join(stuff) # this will be unicode if any value in stuff is unicode
encoded = text.encode("utf-8") # or use whatever encoding you prefer
fout.write(encoded)
```